# Switching the value with order

Tags: python

Is there a pythonic shorter version for the flowing code:

```
def method(a,b)
    if a > b:
        pass       
    else:
        a, b = b, a
```

Comment: pythonic != shorter; your function is fine as written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single assignment:

```
a, b = max(a, b), min(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is shorter:

```
def method(a,b)
    if a <= b:
        a, b = b, a
```

I suppose you could compress it into one line, but I don't know if it counts as more readable:

```
(a,b) = (b,a) if a <= b else (a,b)
```

Comment: Why not `a < b`?

Comment: @Piinthesky Because `a > b` evaluates to true **only** if a is larger than b. In all other cases (including equality), it is false.

Comment: Forgive this Python beginner question - what is the point of switching equal values?

Comment: @Piinthesky This is useful in certain situations, such as when `a` and `b` contain instances of classes with custom [operator functions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html). What this means basically is that they are equal because the person who wrote the class says they are. However they are truly separate objects, and switching the references around can affect things later down the program.

Answer (score 0):

One easy simplification is to flip the conditional case. The default return for a Python method is `None`, so the end result is the same as your snippet.

```
def method(a, b):
  if a <= b:
    a, b = b, a
```

We might be able to do more if you provided more context around your question; what are you trying to accomplish?